# how to install cpp_check.vmb in vim

Tags: vim, plugins, nerdtree, cppcheck

I've found that `cpp_check` vim plugin on http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5192 and I want to install it my `vim` plugin list. I have downloaded the `.vmb` from the link above, copied and I ran `vim cpp_cppcheck.vmb` & `:so &`, which copied the `cpp_check.vim` to `~/.vim/ftplugin/`, I tried it out but it ddn't seem to work. I then moved the `.vim`file into the `plugin/` directory which allows me to execute `:Cppcheck` on a new vim instance but as soon as I launch `:NERDTree` in my `vim` environment, I loose the command `:Cppcheck` why is this and how can I fix it?

And if I close NERDTree again with `NERDTreeClose`, I get the `:Cppcheck` functionality back, too.
My `.vimrc` looks like:

```
$ cat ~/.vimrc
" Pathogen
execute pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags() " generate helptags for everything in 'runtimepath'
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on

set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set autoindent
set autochdir

set tags=./tags,tags;$HOME

nmap <F8> :TagbarToggle<CR>

if has('cscope')
    set cscopetag cscopeverbose
    if has('quickfix')
        set cscopequickfix=s-,c-,d-,i-,t-,e-
    endif

    cnoreabbrev csa cs add
    cnoreabbrev csf cs find
    cnoreabbrev csk cs kill
    cnoreabbrev csr cs reset
    cnoreabbrev css cs show
    cnoreabbrev csh cs help

    command -nargs=0 Cscope cs add $VIMSRC/src/cscope.out $VIMSRC/src
endif

" g:CCTreeCscopeDb = "./cscope.out"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is meant to be a C++ ftplugin.

Activate filetype plugins in your vimrc

Comment: I have `filetype plugin indent on` in my `.vimrc`

Comment: `Cppcheck` is for C & C++, see: http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/: *Cppcheck is a static analysis tool for C/C++ code*

Comment: I know Cppcheck is supposed to support C, but given the name of the ftplugin, it (the ftplugin)'ll only support C++. Rename it to `~/.vim/ftplugin/c_cppcheck.vim` or move it to `~/.vim/ftplugin/c` to support C files. Note: ftplugin definitions are only activated/enbled on buffers with a filetype matching the filetype of the ftplugin.

Comment: Yes, that was it! I didn't know/realize that the letters before the underscore(_) directly relate with the filetype...! If you move this into an answer, I'll be happy to accept it! Thanks!